# Initialization in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to do this exercise. I keep getting errors.

> "Create a Triangle class with properties to store the length of each side. Triangles are called scalene when all three sides are of different lengths, isosceles when two sides have the same length, or equilateral when all three sides have the same length. Create an initializer for your class that takes three arguments and properly sets the class properties. Next, create a second initializer to use when your triangle is equilateral. Remember that all three sides will be the same length, so this method should only take one argument, but should still set all three properties.

My code:

```
class Triangle {

   var sideA: Int
   var sideB: Int
   var sideC: Int

   init(sideA: Int, sideB: Int, sideC: Int) {

      self.sideA = sideA
      self.sideB = sideB
      self.sideC = sideC
   }

   override convenience init() {

      //I can figure this part out, no problem.
   }

   // I cannot figure out the next part.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're saying you can figure out the insides of the convenience init yourself:

Add a parameter to your convenience init, remove the `override` unless you're overriding something (doesn't look like it), and close the class definition with a `}`. You're done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I just figured out my errors, using your explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: @AllocSystems Having unbalanced numbers of opening and closing braces often gives you weird errors and makes Xcode's code completion suggest stupid things. Not sure if that turned out to be the problem, but "I keep getting errors" certainly sounded like it.

Comment: Even numbers of brackets isn't my problem. My main problem is, How do I put in two initializers into the same class that represent different things. I have done the one for equilateral triangles, what about isosceles ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be stuck on the convenience init part.

As the question suggests, your initializer for equilateral triangles should take 1 parameter, so let's add one:

```
convenience init(sideLength: Int) {

}
```

Every convenience inititalizer must call a designated constructor or another convenience constructor. In this case, you can just call the other designated constructor that takes 3 parameters.

```
convenience init(sideLength: Int) {
    self.init(sideA: ???, sideB: ???, sideC: ???)
}
```

You're almost done. You just need to figure out the parameters.

I think at this point you can guess what the three parameters are. Have a go!

Answer here:

> `self.init(sideA: sideLength, sideB: sideLength, sideC: sideLength)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to stackoverflow and I have to say, you guys are so helpful. Should have come here earlier! Thank you!

Comment: @AllocSystems If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: @Sweeper: Nice way to write an answer. And please forgive me if my answer is too similar to yours. Anyway you have my upvote. P.S. I think this answer should be the accepted one, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to provide an initializer to create an equilateral Triangle

```
class Triangle {

    var sideA: Int
    var sideB: Int
    var sideC: Int

    init(sideA: Int, sideB: Int, sideC: Int) {

        self.sideA = sideA
        self.sideB = sideB
        self.sideC = sideC
    }

    convenience init(equilateralWithEdge edge:Int) {
        self.init(sideA: edge, sideB: edge, sideC:edge)
    }

}
```

Now you can build an equilateral Triangle writing

```
let triangle = Triangle(equilateralWithEdge: 10)
```

Test

```
triangle.sideA // 10
triangle.sideB // 10
triangle.sideC // 10
```

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting the hang of it. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out what you put there, but there's something else I don't understand. How can I put another initializer into the same class representing an isosceles triangle? Can it be done in the same class?

Comment: @AllocSystems: In this case you could add this init `convenience init(isolsceleWithLeg leg:Int, andBase base:Int) {
        self.init(sideA: leg, sideB: leg, sideC:base)
    }`